# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' angular 5 with pug

Tags: angular, pug, angular5

I've got the following error when launching my Angular app.
this problem happens only when i am using pug but the code works fine with html.

this is my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; 
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component'; 

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,  
    HeroesComponent, 
  ], 
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and this is my pug

```
h2 {{ hero.name | uppercase}} Details
div
  span id: 
  | {{hero.id}}
div
  span name: 
  | {{hero.name}}


input([(ngmodel)]='hero.name', placeholder='name')
```

any idea how to convert that line in such a way to make angular understand that line: `input([(ngmodel)]='hero.name', placeholder='name')`

Comment: @Sajeetharan, might not as he is saying it is working without pug.

Comment: Typos: `[(ngModel)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error coz of case sensitive :

It's `ngModel` not `ngmodel` .

---

So Change :

```
input([(ngmodel)]='hero.name', placeholder='name')
```

To :

```
input([(ngModel)]='hero.name', placeholder='name')
```

Comment: @tareknoaman, Glad to here that , Will you please accept the answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

please use correct syntax ([ngModel] instead of [(ngModel)]